# composite index: does the order of columns matter in sql server/linq to sql?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I'm in visual studio, looking to create a composite index on 2 columns for several tables. There are 2 columns: UserID is in all tables and acts as the foreign key; then, each table has its own key to refer to the parts of the object, such as phone, address... Like this:

```
TablePhones:
PhoneID  | UserID | PhonePrefix | PhoneNumber | PhoneExtention

TableAddresses:
AddressID | UserID | AddressStreet1 | AddressStreet2 | AddressCity...
```

**Note that users can have more than 1 address and more than 1 phone number.**

I'm using linq to sql and the where clauses queries to get the objects look like this:

```
read queries:
where x.UserID == TheUserID

update/delete queries:
where x.UserID == TheUserID && x.PhoneID = ThePhoneID
```

At the moment, the primary keys are on PhoneID and AddressID and I'm looking to create composite indexes on PhoneID/UserID and AddressID/UserID. Is the order of the columns in the database fine as it is or should I move UserID in first position for all tables.

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order of columns in table doesn't matter; at least for SQLServer. The important thing is in which order fields are listed in an index. Queries with conditions on leading column[s] will very benefit from the index.

If your primary key is clustered, you can create index on only `userID`, no need for composite key. Anyway, it will have a reference to clustered key.

Comment: What if UserID is not unique? Is that a problem for primary key?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you right. You say you already have a primary key.

Comment: If you are thinking about redesigning table structure, and use composite primary keys, take the following into account : If you need to refer a record from these tables in another table, it's better to create a surrogate PK and unique constraint on (userId, PhoneId) and (UserId,AddressId) than to have a composite PK

Comment: Yes, the primary key is currently on AddressID and PhoneID, which are unique

Comment: Does the order of columns in the WHERE clause also matter?

Comment: Optimizer is free to choose whatever order of evaluation it decides is better based on statistics and indexes. It might not choose the best order if you have some subqueries or udfs, or stats never updated, but usually you don't need to worry about order of expressions in where

Comment: @RickNZ: I'm talking about the order of the columns in the DB. Should they be 1.UserID 2.AddressID or 1.AddressID 2.UserID knowing that users can have multiple addresses. And then I'll make the order of the where operators match the order of the columns.